# 'Settings' is inaccessible due to its protection level

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, class, asp.net-mvc-4, access-modifiers

I have the following `Utilities.CS` file in my `App_Code` folder as "helper" methods used throughout my MVC4 application (Build Action set to Compile)

There is a break-point in the code as indicated...

The application compiles (Ctrl-Shift-B) with no errors but when I run the application I get a `CS0122: 'Settings' is inaccessible due to its protection level` at the subsequent `return` statement after the break-point.

The `AdminGroup` setting is defined as `public` in the Settings Designer

The break-point line never gets hit, probably due to run-time compilation error... but if I've compiled it, why is it re-compiling at run-time?

(Sorry, I'm new to MVC so no really sure what's going on)

```
namespace MyApplication
{
    public class Utilities
    {
        public static string UserID
        {
            get
            {
                return Regex.Replace(WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name, @".+\\", "").ToUpper();
            }
        }

        public static bool IsAdmin
        {
            get
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Break point on this line");
                return (HttpContext.Current.User.IsInRole(Properties.Settings.Default.AdminGroup));
            }
        }
    }

}
```

**UPDATE**

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <auto-generated>
//     This code was generated by a tool.
//     Runtime Version:4.0.30319.42000
//
//     Changes to this file may cause incorrect behavior and will be lost if
//     the code is regenerated.
// </auto-generated>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

namespace MyApplication.Properties {


    [global::System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CompilerGeneratedAttribute()]
    [global::System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editors.SettingsDesigner.SettingsSingleFileGenerator", "14.0.0.0")]
    internal sealed partial class Settings : global::System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsBase {

        private static Settings defaultInstance = ((Settings)(global::System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsBase.Synchronized(new Settings())));

        public static Settings Default {
            get {
                return defaultInstance;
            }
        }

    //
    // Other Settings Removed
    //

        [global::System.Configuration.ApplicationScopedSettingAttribute()]
        [global::System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()]
        [global::System.Configuration.DefaultSettingValueAttribute("MYDOMAIN\\ADMINGROUP")]
        public string AdminGroup {
            get {
                return ((string)(this["AdminGroup"]));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Show code for `Properties`. Click on `Properties` and press `F12`

Comment: Can you `Properties` class?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

This error is because of `Settings` class is `internal`.

I assumed that you have created and modified settings from visual studio project properties section settings. `Right click on project > Properties > Settings.` There is a drop down menu called Access Modifier that you need to change from internal to public.

[image]

**For more information on internal keyword:**
[The internal keyword is an access modifier for types and type members. Internal types or members are accessible only within files in the same assembly](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7c5ka91b.aspx)

Comment: Odd... on one machine, my code compiles with it as "Internal".  On the other it will only compile as "Public".  It doesn't matter in my usage except for best practices but it's odd.

Answer (score -2):

This error can also appear if you've forgotten to reference the namespace of the Resource file in your view, even when the Access Modifier is changed to public as @Rahul Nikate's answer specifies.

```
@using MyApp.Config
```

In .NET Core, this might typically sit in `_ViewImports.cshtml` to be shared across all views in the associated Area.